# Ubuntu gone after installing windows 8

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I had two OS on my PC Windows 7 and Ubuntu in separated partitions. After trying to change windows 7 to windows 8, it works good but Ubuntu has disappeared and the weird thing is that, its partition appeared on my hard drive but I can't switch between them. How can I get Ubuntu back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case.

Boot from your installation media (DVD/USB). Select the 'Try Ubuntu' option, this should run Ubuntu from the DVD/USB then you can open a terminal window & enter the command that Nikolay mentions.

Thumbs up Nikolay, was looking for this myself the other day :D

Comment: Please do not use answers as comments. Your answer does not provide a solution for the question.

Comment: Don't have enough 'rep' to put it in a comment, otherwise I would have done so

Comment: Oh! Wow, so this is the answer... :O

Answer (score 0):

You should install grub again (because windows rewrites you MBR). To do this boot from your ubuntu cd/usb and  type in terminal:
`sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt && sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`

In this case `sda4` is the linux partition.

Then reboot and grub menu should be there and you will see Ubuntu too.